# Remove characters from html via python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I am trying to edit via python an .html file.
I want to delete the following string `«</p><p></p><p class="dropcap">` from the html string I parsed from a url via `html_content = requests.get(url).text` and replace it with just the `«` character. I have to do the replacement and not just the deletion because I want this part of the code to remain in all the other places.

I've tried `html_content = html_content.replace("«</p><p></p><p class=\"dropcap\">", "«")` with no success.

Sample of the file:

```
(...)<br clear="all"/><hr noshade="" size="2"/><b id="Page6"> TEXT TEXT TEXT</b><p align="center"><b>TEXT TEXT TEXT</b></p><p></p><p class="dropcap">«</p><p></p><p class="dropcap">TEXT TEXT TEXT»</p><p></p><p class="dropcap">TEXT TEXT TEXT</p><p></p><p class="dropcap">TEXT TEXT TEXT</p><br clear="all"/><p align="right" class="signature"><b>TEXT TEXT TEXT</b></p><br/><br clear="all"/><hr size="1" width="33%"/><p align="center"><u>TEXT TEXT TEXT</u></p><p align="center"><b>«TEXT TEXT TEXT»</b></p><p align="center"><p>TEXT TEXT TEXT</p></p><p>TEXT TEXT TEXT<b>TEXT TEXT TEXT</b></p><p>TEXT TEXT TEXT <b>«TEXT TEXT TEXT»:</b><i>«TEXT TEXT TEXT</i> TEXT TEXT TEXT <sup><b>1</b></sup> (...)
```

The funny thing is that I have 3 replacements on the row (but only this one doesn't work):

```
html_content = html_content.replace("class=\"subtitle", "align=\"center")
html_content = html_content.replace('«</p><p></p><p class=\"dropcap\">', '«')
html_content = html_content.replace("Pg1 - NEW", "Page 1 - NEW")
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: try wrapping your strings with single quotes to get the double quotes around dropcap

Comment: @bn_ln if you mean that `html_content = html_content.replace('«</p><p></p><p class=\"dropcap\">', '«')` still the same result. It doesn't replace it

Comment: Could you include a sample of the file?

Comment: @bn_ln I added it on the question

Comment: Your code for replacing works for me with the given example. Please check if you update the html file correctly.

Comment: @bitflip That's very strange because I have 3 replaces in the row, (and this one is the second one) and only this one doesn't work for some reason. `html_content = html_content.replace("class=\"subtitle", "align=\"center")

  html_content = html_content.replace('«</p><p></p><p class=\"dropcap\">', '«')
  
  html_content = html_content.replace("Pg1 - NEW", "Page 1 - NEW")`

Comment: the other occurrences don't have the `«` at the start

Comment: @bn_ln i meant 3 different replaces (see code above)

Comment: I know what you mean, but they don't match your pattern because they don't start with `«`

Comment: oh I am sorry, i thought you wrote it before i edited it adding those 3 lines. But still that's what I am saying that it seams very odd. The second line doesn't work on my code, but because of the 3rd one working, I know for sure that the html file is updating correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import re

CLEANR = re.compile('«</p><p></p><p class="dropcap">') 

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
   cleantext = re.sub(CLEANR, '', raw_html)
   return cleantext
```

the resulting output

[image]

Comment: That's not what I want. As i mentioned I can't just erase the sting, i need to replace it with "", because I need the same string in other parts of the html code. I only want to delete it after the `«` character.

Comment: For example `<p></p><p class="dropcap">«</p><p></p><p class="dropcap">text</p>` --> `<p></p><p class="dropcap">«text</p>`